# Hibernate CrudRepository - Select first row

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I would like to fetch just the first row from a table by using my Repository class.
At the moment im stuck at this point:

```
import com.bodymate.springend.mvc.hiberentity.Trainer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface TrainerRepository extends CrudRepository<Trainer, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM trainer LIMIT 1")
    public Trainer getFirst();
}
```

The keyword 'LIMIT' is not accepted by the compiler...

And also I cant use methods like findFirstBy... or get getFirstBy... because the all expect a selection criteria. And I think it's not the best soulution to pass a selection criteria that would be true for all rows (something like findFirstByIdLessThan( 99999 )).

How can I achieve this using hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper method with a Pageable parameter and use it in your method specified as default implementation(or separately in a service/custom repository):

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM trainer t")
List<Trainer> getLimited(Pageable page);

default Optional<Trainer> getFirst() {
  return getLimited(PageRequest.of(0,1))
           .stream()
           .findFirst();
}
```

Comment: I figured out that I have to user List<> or Slice as return type, so i ended up with this definition:  `List<Trainer> getFirst(Pageable pageable);`
I am getting the error: "Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.bodymate.springend.mvc.repository.TrainerRepository.getFirst(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property getFirst found for type Trainer!"

Comment: Whoops, sorry for a type. I've updated code snippet in my answer. I guess you removed your @Query that should have stayed there.